# Cannot set mapped association Id during PrePersist event

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an article entity belongs to a category entity:

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticlesRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Article {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $categoryId;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="articles")
     */
    private $category;
}
```

and I manually set  `category_id` field in `PrePersist` event:

```
/** @ORM\PrePersist */
public function setProperPosition(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs $event){
    $this->categoryId = 1;
}
```

But is does not work. The field (`category_id`) remains null on the database.

Comment: Remove the parameter from the function `public function setProperPosition() { ... }` and try again, if you are running into any errors add them here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have two properties for the same column. You have `$category` and `$categoryId`, which basically reference the same *value*.

So basically you a declaring the same column twice. That's what's likely giving you trouble.

Anyway, try it this way:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ArticlesRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="articles")
     */
    private $category;

    /** @ORM\PrePersist */
    public function setProperPosition(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $this->category = $event
            ->getEntityManager()
            ->getReference(Category::class, 1);
    }
}
```

I simplified all the required namespaces. Make sure you `use` them so the are imported and available in the file.

(To make it clear, remove the redundant `$categoryId` definition)